# Windows batch file for renaming file at specified interval

Tags: windows, batch-file, loops, timer

I would like to write a windows batch file for the purpose of renaming a file every 25 seconds. I would also like the batch file to terminate after 300 seconds have passed. How would I go about doing this? Here is what I have thusfar.

```
START

RENAME test.g test.go

SLEEP 25

RENAME test.go test.g

GOTO START
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need the sleep command, you can [download it here](http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html).

then you can do something like this:

```
echo this is a test > test.txt
SET x=
:START
CALL SET /a x = %x% +1
rename test.* test.%x%

CALL SET /a y = %x% * 25

IF '%x%' == '300' GOTO END

CALL SLEEP 25
GOTO START

:END
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is not too difficult. There are a bunch of well-known batch tricks, such as mis-using ping to sleep (which saves you from having to integrate a non-standard tool) and we can then come up with the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set n=0
:start
ren test.g test.go
ping localhost -n 26>nul 2>&1
ren test.go test.g
set /a n+=25
if %n% LSS 300 goto start
endlocal
```

`setlocal` and `endlocal` will ensure that all environment variables we create and modify will remain only in scope of the batch file itself. The command

```
ping localhost -n 26 >nul 2>&1
```

will wait 25 seconds (because the first ping will be immediate and every subsequent one incurs a one-second delay) while throwing away all normal and error output (`>nul 2>&1`).

Finally we are keeping track of how long we waited so far in the `%n%` variable and only if *n* is still below 300 we continue looping. You might as well do it with a for loop, though:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set n=300
set /a k=n/25
for /l %%i in (1,1,%k%) do (
    ren test.g test.go
    ping localhost -n 26>nul 2>&1
    ren test.go test.g
)
endlocal
```

which will first calculate how often it would need to loop and then just iterate the calculated number of times.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using windows, then i assume you can use vbscript.

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFile1 = "file.txt"
strFile2 = "new.txt"
While 1=1
    Set objFile1 = objFS.GetFile(strFile1)
    objFile1.Name = strFile2
    Set objFile1 = Nothing
    WScript.Echo "sleeping.."
    WScript.Sleep (25 * 60)
    Set objFile2 = objFS.GetFile(strFile2)
    objFile2.Name = strFile1
    Set objFile2 = Nothing
    WScript.Sleep (300 * 60)
Wend
```

save the above as myscript.vbs and on command line

```
c:\test> cscript /nologo myscript.vbs
```